# Use-def analysis on struct fields in llvm

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I have a code which involves struct in C. I have converted this to LLVM IR. The struct field access are converted to GEP instructions with index based access.

Is it possible to do use-def analysis on such struct fields ?  I want to remove struct field which is not being accessed anywhere in the module.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, it certainly is. Are you asking if there is some out-of-the-box solution?

Comment: I do that in the compiler I work on. It's not simple and I don't think a one-size solution will fit all needs, so I'm going to vote to close this as too open-ended and lacking in focus.

Comment: @arrowd can you please tell me high level outline for this ? I tried to do for(auto fieldType : StructType) { for (auto use : fieldType->users()) {...}}  . But I guess I cannot get users() for a type. So should I filter GEPs and check if it is a struct access and then do users() on that ?